# How to check the status of a foreach() loop in Php?

Tags: php, foreach

I need to check the status of a foreach loop after importing an sql file into a new database. I'm not sure how to do it.

```
//import tables into new db
$newconn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $newDB);
$filename = 'tables.sql'; 
$op_data = '';
$lines = file($filename);
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')//This IF Remove Comment Inside SQL FILE
    {
        continue;
    }
    $op_data .= $line;
    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')//Breack Line Upto ';' NEW QUERY
    {
        $newconn->query($op_data);
        $op_data = '';
    }
}

if(foreach == SUCCESS){
echo 'Success! Gabriel escaped Negan!';
}else{
echo 'Crap! Father Gabriel died!';
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with foreach == success ... ?

Comment: What do you mean by status exactly. If it's finished? What iteration it's on?

Comment: @abney317: I want to tell the program what to do when the foreach terminates.

Comment: @scaisEdge: I mean if it has successfully finished.

Comment: Define "successfully finished". If it hits a fatal exception, the remainder of the code will not be executed. Everything else is up to you.

Comment: Could you show the file `tables.sql`?

Comment: Your code will not run properly, because there can be other line types ended with ";". Example: `/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;`

Comment: @aendeerei: What do you mean? It works for me.

Comment: I meant: Let's suppose that you have a line like my example line in your file, before the actual `CREATE TABLE ...;` statement. Such lines are special comment lines. They end in `;`. So, if that's the case, your php code will run that line first. Therefore your `query()` call will fail.

Comment: @aendeerei: Ok I understand. But I've been running this 10 times already and never fails.

Comment: Then it's ok. I just wanted to make you aware of that case ;-)

Comment: @aendeerei: Yes thanks bro. Much appreciated :-D

Comment: You are welcome. Just so you know: Normally, such lines are automatically appended to the sql files created when you choose to export sql scripts from your mysql client software (mysql workbench, sequel pro, etc). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just wanting to run code after your foreach loop has completed then you can just put that code after the loop.
The code you put after the loop will no be run until the foreach loop has finished.

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    //loop code
}

//code to be run after loop ends
```